# initializer_list as argument to an array reference parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reference, initializer-list

Is the following call to `foo` valid? GCC seems happy with it, while Clang gives a "no matching function" error for `foo`; and a note that `N` couldn't be inferred.

```
template <unsigned N>
void foo(const int (&x)[N]) {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  foo({1,2,3});
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler versions are they?

Comment: GCC 4.10.0 (20140810) and Clang version 3.6.0 (trunk 215435). (I also tried on another machine with recent builds of each.)

Comment: ...does that imply that GCC should give an error?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be deducing an array from your initializer list argument

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: With the adoption of the resolution of [CWG issue 1591](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1591) at the Committee's November 2014 meeting, the code in the OP is now allowed. The compiler can now deduce both the type and the number of elements in the array.

---

<s>§14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]/p5:</s>

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - [...]
> - A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (8.5.4) but the parameter does not have
>     `std::initializer_list` or reference to possibly cv-qualified
>     `std::initializer_list` type.
> - [...]

Your initializer list is a non-deduced context, so clang properly rejects your code.

Conceivably, g++ could support deduction in this case as an extension. However, as it [rejects](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/645b877ed6879d45) this code with a "deduced conflicting values" error:

```
template<unsigned N>
  struct C { };

template <unsigned N>
void foo(C<N>, const int (&x)[N]) {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  foo(C<4>(), {1,2,3});
  return 0;
}
```

It looks like a bug to me. (In the call to `foo` in the code above, the compiler is supposed to deduce `N` only from the first argument according to the standard, so there should be no conflict. g++ deduced `N` from the second argument as well, creating a conflict. This altered the behavior of a well-formed program, which isn't allowed for a conforming extension.)

Comment: @40two Which one? The original or the modified version?

Comment: version 12.0 Update 2

Comment: Sorry didn't get it at first, the one that the OP posted. The one you posted generates the same error as well.

Comment: @40two Yeah, OK. MSVC isn't very useful for reasoning about standard conformance, anyway.